# correctly punctuate each sentence to make it meaningful

Tags: punctuation, descriptive-grammar

Ten(10) editor-in-chiefs from two(2)media houses were present at the seminar

During the nineteen eighties(1980's) there was severely famine

All seven former heads-of-states were at the inaugural ceremony

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s homework without research.

Answer (score -2):

Ten(10) editor-in-chiefs, from two(2) media houses, were present at the seminar

During the nineteen eighties(1980's), there was severely famine

All seven former heads-of-states, were at the inaugural ceremony